# error con material ui react

Tags: reactjs

//Tengo un appBar de material ui que cuando el usaurio baja, el header se esconde, y cuando el usuario sube tiene que aparecer otra vez el header pero no logro que vuelva aparecer sino hasta que el usaurio haya subito todo, no se por que no baja,este es mi componente

```
interface Props {
    /**
     * Injected by the documentation to work in an iframe.
     * You won't need it on your project.
     */
    window?: () => Window;
    children: React.ReactElement;
  }

function HideOnScroll(props: Props) {
  const { children, window } = props;
  // Note that you normally won't need to set the window ref as useScrollTrigger
  // will default to window.
  // This is only being set here because the demo is in an iframe.
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({ target: window ? window() : undefined });

  return (
    <Slide appear={false} direction="down" in={!trigger}>
      {children}
    </Slide>
  );
}

export default function HideAppBar(props: Props) {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <HideOnScroll >
        <Header />
      </HideOnScroll>
      <Toolbar />
      <Container>
      {[...new Array(200)].map(
              () => `Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.`,
            )
            .join('\n')}
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

este componente lo saque directamente de la documentacion de material ui en el apartado componentes, este archivo lo estoy llamando desde otro componente, y el componente me pide una propiedad children que espera un componente, no se para que usa ese componente y no se que componente agregarle, me pueden ayudar?

Comment: si entran en [https://codesandbox.io/s/h8ls7?file=/index.tsx] puede ver el archivo `index.tsx` que en el componente `Demo` tambien da un error

Comment: Si pasas como parámetro `ReactDOM.render(<Demo><div>algo</div></Demo>, document.querySelector('#root'));` ya no sale la advertencia. Y el scroll me funciona correcto a mi, se muestra/esconde cuando debe, no cuando llega al final como dices tu